# Blurring a texture taking too much time in unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, blur

I'm making a 2d game for android where I want to make the background blur when a popup opens.

I have tried so many techniques.

1. Making two camera. Blurred main camera and changing culling mask of secondary camera to the popup layer.
2. Using grabpass shader in a material and adding it to the background of popup.
3. Capturing screenshot, blurring the texture and adding it to background of popup as sprite.

Everything doing exact what I want to do. But either they are eating FPS or taking a huge time at first time.

So is there any way or workaround which will not slow it down or lag?

Comment: Please show your code. What blur shader are you using, etc.

Comment: Showing game source code is not possible. Im giving you the shader link. Though I deleted the part of distortion and it saves my 6-7FPS. https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/solved-dynamic-blurred-background-on-ui.345083/

Comment: While you don't have to provide actual source code, you do need to provide the closest thing to a working example. SO isn't a forum.

Comment: Ok I will then make a demo project and give you.